# Why does the electric field strength formula stay valid when in different environment?

Tags: electrostatics

Why is the electric field strength stay valid when in different environment  (environments that doesn't include free space) , even thought the electric field strength formula is in relation with free space permittivity .

E = Q/(4πε0*r²) is in relation with the free space permittivity ε0 i thought that the formula will only be valid when working with electric fields in free space but apparently , it is valid for other environments (materials) like an atom or an electron in air .

Comment: Why would you assume that it's unchanged? Could you clarify where you saw that?

Comment: i am not sure does it change when we r not working in free space?

Comment: Of course it does change. But your question isn't "How does it change?" but "Why doesn't it change?" So you're assuming that it doesn't change. Which is why you should clarify why you do.

Comment: Inside materials, You can work with $\epsilon_0$ and include other source terms such as polarisation charge density. Or another method is to artificially change $\epsilon$ and neglect the other source terms, the effect is the same, there is nothing special about the actual physics inside materials that actually change the constant of permitivity, its just that we can "think of it" as something different ,

Comment: The field caused by a standard charge density inside of a material is the same as if it was in a vacuum. However the NET field is different as you have other sources of the electric field

Comment: The electric (displacement) field takes the form $D=\epsilon E=\epsilon_0 E +P$ where $\epsilon$ is the permittivity of the medium, and $P$ is polarization. You can see this in any text on electromagnetism.